# How to convert React.DOM elements to JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-dom

When it comes to React JSX code standards:
How would I go about refactoring the following code bellow to JSX?

```
const ListContainer = (props) => React.DOM.table({ className: 'list-container' }, [
    React.DOM.thead({ key: 'firstName' }, React.DOM.tr({}, [
        React.DOM.th({ key: 'lastName' }, null, 'headshot'),
        React.DOM.th({ key: 'id' }, null, 'First Name'),
        React.DOM.th({ key: 'last-h' }, null, 'Last Name')
    ])),
    React.DOM.tbody({ key: 'tbody' }, props.personList.map((person, i) =>
        React.createElement(ListRow, { key: `person-${i}`, person })))
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See a demo at: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxmPVv?editors=1111)

Translated below:

```
const ListContainer = props => (
    <table className="list-container">
        <thead>
            <th>
                headshot
            </th>
            <th>
                First Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Last Name
            </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {
                props.personList.map((person, i) => {
                    return <ListRow key={`person-${i}`} person={person} />
                })
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
);
```

Of course for the above you would need to use babel transpiler (let me know if you need more info on this).

You can then use your const as follows in JSX:

```
<ListContainer />
```

Comment: hi @sammysaglam I'm confused about combining the two, in another words the correct syntax for:  React.DOM.th({ key: 'last-h' }, null, 'Last Name') + React.DOM.tbody({ key: 'tbody' }, props.personList.map((person, i) =>
        React.createElement(ListRow, { key: `person-${i}`, person })))

Comment: So, I translated your code to JSX; however, I would not recommend using the key property except for on the <ListRow> component => the reason being that React uses the key as a special string attribute when creating lists of elements (e.g. using the "map" method as you have above).

"Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity" (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). Of couse, the "key" property doesn't hurt, but it's redundant above.

Comment: @rimatla13 I added a demo at (CodePen)
 — [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxmPVv?editors=1111]

Comment: That makes sense @sammysaglam. Thank you very much!